# Java list null check before Stream and return as Optional

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I am getting list of objects from API

```
public Optional<List<Employee>> getEmployeeData (String deptId){

     List<Employee> employee = departmentClient.employeeData(deptId);

     //Based on some condition I am filtering employee list but before that I want to check  for null for list.

    return Optional.ofNullable(employee).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(e -> e.getType != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 }
```

But I think as method return type is `Optional<>` this is giving error. How can I check null for the `List` before the `Stream` and return as an `Optional<List<..>>`

Comment: in this case if employee list is null then it is throwing `NullPointerException` error

Comment: Irrelevant to the problem, but out of curiosity: why is the method designed to return`Optional<List<Employee>>` instead of `List<Employee>` which could be empty if no `employees` match required criteria? `Optional` is convenient for wrapping possible `null` values when - for example no match is found, but an empty collection communicates this better and with less code.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(employee)` should not even be required given that `employee` is a `Collection` and you don't further need an empty check while using `stream` for your example shared.

Comment: Unless you have very special requirements that you don’t present, I recommend that `departmentClient.employeeData()` never returns `null` but an empty list if there are no employee data to return. And that your method, `getEmployeeData()`, doesn’t return an `Optional` but just a `List<Employee>` and again an empy list if there are no data to return.

Answer (score 3):

You returned `List<Employee>` while your method signature is `Optional<List<Employee>>`

Try this one:

```
return employee != null ? Optional.of(employee.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(e -> e.getType != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())) : Optional.ofNullable(Collections.emptyList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't work because the result of `Optional` is `List` and you collect it through the `Stream` pipelines back to the `List`.

Using **Java 8** you can wrap all your solution inside `Optional` or better use the advantage of the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) instead:

```
Optional<List<Employee>> o = Optional
        .ofNullable(employees)                  // employees can be null, right?
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())        // ... if so, then empty List
        .stream()                               // Stream<Employee>
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)               // Stream<Employee> filtered as non-nulls
        .filter(e -> e.getType() != null)       // Stream<Employee> with non-null field
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(  
            Collectors.toList(),                // Collected to List<Employee>
            Optional::of));                     // Collected to Optional<List<Employee>>
```

The  [`Collectors::collectingAndThen(Collector<T,A,R> downstream, Function<R,RR> finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) method behaves as usual Collector providing a subsequent mapping function taking the collected result. In our case, we simply wrap the `List` into `Optional` to be returned.

- Collector `downstream`  collects to `List<Employee>`
- Function `finisher` maps `List<Employee>` to `Optional<List<Employee>>`

---

With **Java 9** and higher using [`Optional::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--), the beginning might be little different:

```
Optional<List<Employee>> o = Optional
        .ofNullable(employees)                  // null-safe employees
        .stream()                               // Stream<List<Employees>>
        .flatMap(List::stream)                  // Stream<Employees>
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) 
        ......
```

Answer (score 2):

And yet another option:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(employee)
        .map(list -> list.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(e -> e.getType() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The lambda inside `.map(...)` is executed only if the `emploee` list is not null, otherwise an empty `Optional` is returned.